# Assembly Segmentation Fault

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, libc

I encountered an Error during running of the following Assembly Code

```
#cpuid using C library Functions
.section .data
output:
 .asciz "The Processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n"
.section .bss
 .lcomm buffer, 12
.section .text
.globl main
main:
 movq $0, %rax
 cpuid
 movq $buffer, %rdi
 movq %rbx, (%rdi)
 movq %rdx, (%rdi)
 movq %rcx, (%rdi)
 pushq $buffer
 pushq $output
 call printf
 addq $8, %rsp
 pushq $0
 call exit
```

It encountered segmentation fault at the part of C library Calling:call printf
It is running in x86_64 mode.
Anything I missed out during compiling of x64 code with regards to the c library? Or is there something wrong with the code

Thanks

Comment: might want to increase %rdi by an appropriate amount between those movq's

Comment: Thanks everyone, I solved the issue.
It was the wrong lib that I loaded works fine after I ld it manually with /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and I replaced the main function with _start.
I ld it as dynamic linking. 
Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 4):

Is the C runtime library's initialization being called?  That has to run first in order for stdout to be set up.  BTW, a stack trace would eliminate doubt as to the cause of the problem.

Also, prevent the %s conversion from overflowing the buffer with %.12s, or just put a NUL byte after buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The assembler calls for 64bit fprintf are seemingly changed, so either link the 32bit library or use the following code:

```
#cpuid using C library Functions
.section .data
output:
 .asciz "The Processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n"
.section .bss
 .lcomm buffer, 12
.section .text
.globl main
main:
 movq $0, %rax
 cpuid
 movq $buffer, %rdi
 movq %rbx, (%rdi)
 movq %rdx, 4(%rdi)
 movq %rcx, 8(%rdi)
 movq $buffer, %rsi #1st parameter
 movq $output, %rdi #2nd parameter
 movq $0, %rax
 call printf
 addq $8, %rsp
 pushq $0
 call exit
```

Comment: your movq instructions do not increment `(%rdi)`, so unless I'm missing something, `movq $buffer, (%rdi)` is simply going to be overwritten by your `movq $output, %rdi` a few lines later. I can see what you are doing, but why use `%rdi` when you're just going to copy `$buffer` to `%rsi` a few lines later anyway?

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with assembly, so a shot in the dark: are both your strings null terminated?

Comment: `.asciz` automatically adds the terminating null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to null-terminate the string you write into $buffer, rather than write on top of one word three times. Also, wallyk is right: are you sure that the CRT is being initialized?

Honestly, you are really much better off writing this program, which calls a C library function, in C. Write the CPUID code as inline assembly inside a __cdecl function, have it write its result to a string pointer, and then call that function from a C program.

```
void GetCPUID( char *toStr )
{
 // inline assembly left as exercise for the reader.. 
 // write ebx to *toStr, ecx to *toStr+4, edx to *toStr+8, and 0 to *toStr+12
}

void PrintCPUID()
{
   char cpuidstr[16];
   GetCPUID( cpuidstr );
   printf( "cpuid: %s\n", cpuidstr );

}
```